# Difference of send POST request with json data or parameter?

Tags: json, post, request

POST request can be sent with url `/api?k=v`. Or send request with json `{"k":"v"}`.

What's the difference of them. Any difference when accept date in back end?
Can I use `getParameter` to get them?

Comment: For the perspective of REST practice, if it can be passed through body, it is preferred, and generally, when querying the response, it can be gotten from the response body.

If there are some cases, for example, some "actions" cannot be put in request body, it can be put in query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference of them?

url /api?k=v use name value pair, which is a feature of [query String](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

json {"k":"v"} this is json format just mentioned at by @WAQAS YOUSAF answer you can send complex data structures which is defined by you. Also with the help of json library like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson) they are easy to parse.

> Any difference when accept date in back end?

No difference to date type just the difference is for k=v you send it via query String, for json you send it in json format. When parse it they are different which mentioned above.

> Can I use getParameter to get them?

You just use getParameter with query String, it is getting the data from parameter map(`request.getParameterMap()`) parameter map will be empty when you send a data on body like below:

```
{action:'Sale'}
```

To see your json body data, you can use the below code:

```
String bodyRequest = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
System.out.println("BodyRequest:" + bodyRequest);
```

And for security perspective; using post with query string is not a secure way because your parameters are seen at apache logs with this way. So it is better to use Post with body request too.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely technical point of view,

If you do not want to use query params at all, you need POST and put your JSON into the request body. Depending on which option you choose, there are differences in how to deal with it in.

For JSON, there is also of course the time it takes to parse it, but that should be negligible.

The advantage JSON has over query strings without JSON inside them is, that you can encode arbitrary complex data structures inside JSON, while plain-text query strings are just one level deep.

From a security point of view, pretty everything has been set.

Comment: what do you mean by "Depending on which option you choose, there are differences in how to deal with it in.". Need to fetch data from body, any other methods?

Comment: "From a security point of view, pretty everything has been set." which one is more secure?

Answer (score 0):

POST with url - /api?k=v

this means you have parameter `k` with value `v` as query parameters of http.

if sending with JSON, you will be sending it with request body of http and you will not be able to use getParameters to retrieve it.